# Start Node in Ignite

Tags: ignite

i want to start ignite node with a configuration name as example-igfs.xml. i have alter this configuration for using IGFS as cache layer for HDFS. but when i execute the below command  for start ignite node i encounter with error: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.(Configuration.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.(Configuration.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.(Configuration.java:456)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.HadoopUtils.safeCreateConfiguration(HadoopUtils.java:334)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.impl.delegate.HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.start(HadoopBasicFileSystemFactoryDelegate.java:129)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error usually comes when ignite can't find required libraries(Jars).

In your case, you have to move JARs to `$IGNITE_HOME\libs` folder.

Create a folder in libs directory, let's say `hadoop-libs` and move all all required JARs to this folder.

I am not expert of hadoop but it seems that you are missing hadoop client and its dependent google guava libraries.